# Conjugate momentum vs translation generator with non-standard kinetic term

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.00219) and for equation (2.5) (associated with the Lagrangian in eq 2.1) there is the claim that for a Lagrangian $L(\varphi,A,\dot{\varphi},\dot{A})$ containing an extra non-standard kinetic term $c \varphi\dot{A}$ (with some constant $c$), the generators for $\varphi$- and $A$-translations are
$$\pi_{\varphi}=p_{\varphi}-cA, \; \pi_{A}=p_A$$ respectively, with $p_{\varphi}$ and $p_{A}$ the conjugate momentums.

My confusions are: (1) Why is there a $-cA$ term difference between the generator of translation vs the conjugate momentum of $\phi$. In classical mechanics, aren't translations generated by the conjugate momentum with $\{\quad ,p_{\varphi}\}$? If we include an extra $-cA$ term in the Poisson bracket doesn't that induce an unwanted change in the $p_A$ direction? And (2) If we integrate by parts the $c\varphi \dot{A}$ term in the action, it seems to change our results for what $p_{\varphi}$ and $p_A$ are. Will this also change our result for what the generators are for $\phi$ and $A$ translations?

For confusion (1), I'm guessing it is related to the fact that $p_{A}\equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{A}}$ is a function of not just $\dot{A}$ but also $\varphi$ due to the non-standard kinetic term. So a change in $\varphi$ should induce a change in the $p_A$ direction? But this all still seem very unfamiliar as I personally don't recall something like the above being discussed in a typical lecture on Noether theorem. Any comments or clarification would be helpful.

Comment: It actually is discussed in pretty much every classical mechanics course. It is simply a particle in a magnetic field (well its integration by parts at least). The fact that the generator of translations is what it is is just the fact that you need a covariant derivative! See for example [Tong's notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/aqm/aqmone.pdf)

Comment: I think the paper you cite is expressing itself poorly - you are correct that the canonical ("conjugate") momentum is always the generator of translations for its conjugate, but the authors of the paper actually agree - if you look at eq. (2.7), they *realize* that applying the exponential of $\pi_\varphi$ is not just a shift in $\varphi$ but also a phase in $A$, i.e. they *know* it is not just "translation in $\varphi$". So whatever they mean by "generator of translations", they don't *actually* mean that $\pi_\varphi$ is the generator of translations...